# Best way to branch on React component name/type

Tags: javascript, reactjs, class, typescript

I have a helper method that needs to return different CSS styles based open the name of the component that is passed in.  The method will look something like this:

```
function (component: Component): ComponentStyles {
    // Branch based on the nanme/type of component
    // and return different sets of CSS styles.
}
```

I'm wondering what is the accepted way to do this in React.  I tried to access `displayName` and `constructor.name`... but it seems as though Typescript only has types for `displayName` if your component is a `SFC`, and using `constructor.name` seems a little hacky...